# jquery remove created elements, children included

Tags: jquery

I want to have this situation where if someone hover's a link, an element should be created dynamically with information about that link.

I know that there are some standard jquery scrips available for that, but for my understanding of jquery i want to make it myself.

I'll show the element like this:

```
    $(".event-date").live("mouseover",function(e){
        var event = e || window.event; 
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).append("<div id='showEventInfoWrap'><div id='closeEventInfo'>Close</div><div id='showEventInfo'></div></div>");
        $("#showEventInfo").load("event-info.php");
    });
```

I use `live()` because the calendar is displayed in an `<div>` element, which changes when the users navigate through the months.

The problem is with hiding the div when:
a) a user clicks the 'close' link; or 
b) a user hovers away from the appeared element.

I tried any of the following options, but neither of them worked:

```
    $("#closeEventInfo").live("click",function(e){
        $(this).parent().attr("id").remove();
        $("#showEventInfoWrap").remove();
        $("#showEventInfoWrap").children().remove();
        $("#showEventInfoWrap").add("#closeEventInfo").add("#showEventInfo").remove();
    });
```

I also tried `empty()` instead of `remove()` but without any result.

Does anybody maybe know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).parent().attr("id").remove();
```

throws an error, causing your script to terminate.
`.attr()` with a single argument returns a string or `undefined`. It's not a jQuery object, hence `.remove` is not defined.

- If you want to remove the parent element, use:

  ```
  $(this).parent().remove();
  ```
- If you want to remove the ID attribute, use:

  ```
  $(this).parent().removeAttr("id");
  ```

`$("#showEventInfoWrap").remove();` would remove the `#showEventInfoWrap` element, *including its childs*.

Comment: You probably wnat to remove the attribute `id`? You need: `$(this).parent().removeAttr('id')`

Comment: No, i want to remove the whole container and its contents, but <code>$("#showEventInfoWrap").remove()</code> doesn't do that..

Comment: @Maurice Show your HTML. I assumed that the `#showEventInfoWrap` selected the container, but by your comment, it's obvious that this is not the case.